# Different output from https links from Java and Php

Tags: java, php

I have an output problem from a simple request get from a web link. Until a month ago there was no problem but lately when I run the request with php I get an error page from the site, which doesn't happen if I run it with Java. I enclose the codes of the two languages.

**JAVA**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL yahoo = new URL("https://turni.xx.it/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                yahoo.openStream()));

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);

    in.close();

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<title>InfoTurni</title>..
```

**PHP**

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
echo $contents;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<title> Generic error </title>..
```

What can it depend on? I also tried to change the php version and also tried to use 'curl' without any success.

Comment: if you print the $contents  directly? tried with curl?

Comment: @Berto99 Always the same mistake but in a formatted way. I tried curl and got the same output.

Comment: sorry which "same" output?

Comment: @Berto99  "<title> Generic error </title>.." also with CURL

Comment: are you running the scripts and the java code in the same machine? are "<title> Generic error </title>" the default page for your website errors?

Comment: @Berto99 java on my pc, while php from a domain on the web. "<title> Generic error </title>" is the output of the website in case of loading error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem just by adding in the header as *User-Agent: PHP*

```
 $opts = ['http' => ['method' => 'GET','header' => ['User-Agent: PHP']]];
 $context = stream_context_create($opts);
 $content = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
 echo htmlentities($content) ;
```